# EF Core SqLite in-memory no such table?

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I configured my ASP.NET Core 2.2 app using UseInMemoryDatabase() and it worked fine. Now I changed it to relational Sqlite in-memory.

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Datasource=file::memory:?cache=shared"));
```

I use this Sqlite in-memory approach in unit tests and it work good. So decided I want to use the same in-memory Sqlite in my app (to test some things, later when app will be ready I'll create sqlite file on disk). The problem is when I starting my app. I receive erros like `SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: USERS'`. I debug my repository class and I found that context has table Users. 
So Sqlite in-memory works fine in unit tests but in real app throws error. Why is that? Thanks for any tips.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create and apply migrations to your in-memory SQLite database. You'll have to apply them every time the app starts, since the database only exists in memory until the application exits.

Comment: In Startup.cs in ConfigureServices() I open connection to database. In Configure() I get context and run context.Database.Migrate(). Still the same error but when I use context.Database.EnsureCreated() it starts without errors. So the migration is not working, just create db schema works.

Comment: Could you please provide instructions for how to do this?

Comment: @dwilli I update to newer version of ASP.NET Core  and currently use in memory Db. services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
      {
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyTestDb");
     
      }
     );